# PHP: Remove URL Param?

Tags: php, url, parameters

I have a function that I call with `?clear-cart` appended to the end of my page; as you can probably guess, this function clears the user's cart.

I call it like this

```
<a href="?clear-cart">Clear Cart</a>
```

Which works great (in that it loads the same page, but now the cart is cleared), except that the URL in the address bar now reads

```
http://test.local/cart?clear-cart
```

Is there anyway to call `?clear-cart` but have the URL return ***without*** the parameter? (Hide it from the user, since I'm only using it for an internal function call??)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could clear the cart and then immediately redirect using header (obviously before any output!).

```
<?php
    header('Location: http://test.local/cart');
    ... clear the cart ...
?>
```

See the [PHP reference manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) for more details.

Comment: @neezer: don't forget `die()` after `header`.

Comment: In this case, I think exit() would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of a GET-request use a POST-request?

Comment: I understood I couldn't use POST requests with `<a>` hyperlinks.

Comment: @neezer, with a little javascript in the onclick event method, anything is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of this should do what you want:

```
if (isset($_GET['clear-cart'])) {

  clear_cart();
  header('Location: http://test.local/');

}
```

Modify to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your cart clearing code in another script and have it redirect back to your page when it's done.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the function that clears the cart, you could redirect the user to the correct URL, using the header() function.

Answer (score 0):

Have the page http://test.local/cart link to the page http://test.local/cart?clear-cart, which then redirects the user back to http://test.local/cart.

> /cart -> /cart?clear-cart -> /cart

```
if (isset($_GET['clear-cart'])) {
  // Do some cart clearing...
  // Redirect back
  header('Location: /cart');
  exit;   // Very important, otherwise the script will continue until it finally redirects
}
```